# Spring 3 @Autowired throws NPE in Formatter

Tags: java, spring, autowired

i've written my own formatter and tried to autowire service into it, but i'm getting `NullPointerException`.

Formatter:

```
@Component
public class DepartmentFormatter implements Formatter<Department> {

    @Autowired
    private DepartmentService departmentService;

    @Override
    public String print(Department department, Locale locale) {
        return department.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public Department parse(String string, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        return departmentService.getByName(string); // NPE thrown here
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class DepartmentServiceImpl implements DepartmentService {

    @Autowired
    private DepartmentDAO departmentDAO;

    /* ... */
}
```

In my spring-servlet.xml i've got

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="net.kurochenko.sampleapp" />
```

[Registering of formatters](http://www.developer.com/java/web/use-the-spring-3-formatter-spi-for-custom-formatting.html):

```
public class FormattingFactory extends FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean {

    @Override
    public void installFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        super.installFormatters(registry);
        registry.addFormatterForFieldAnnotation(new AuthorAnnotationFormatterFactory());
        registry.addFormatterForFieldAnnotation(new DepartmentAnnotationFormatterFactory());
    }   
}
```

FormattingFactory bean

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="formattingFactory" />
```

All aforementioned classes are inside net.kurochenko.sampleapp package.

Autowiring service in `@Controller` works fine. I was searching for solution on google and tried some of them, but exception still remains. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for advises.

Comment: how are you registering the formatter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely registering your formatter with `new DepartmentFormatter()`. It *won't* work that way - spring doesn't get the chance to inject dependencies.

You should register the spring bean instance (created by spring). Be it programatically or via xml.

Comment: How would I do that?